# PHP - Upload CSV to textarea of html and get its value to store in textarea

Tags: php, html, export-to-csv

I want to upload Csv file and output its content in text-area of HTML.
example is i have `92133302,2391235,28743903` in Csv and if i upload this the text-area should contain this number i have tried this but couldn't put it inside the text-area, so what supposed to happen is i will be using the `$_POST[text-area]`; and pass it again to another file but my problem is storing it's value in text-area. i am also using cloud server so i will store all my file to filezilla.

Comment: Where is the code, which you have used to try to achieve your wanted result? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might help you to improve your question.

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

First you need to receive the CSV file you uploaded at your page. Then, you can pass the contents to a variable. Example:

```
$csvData = file_get_contents($fileName);
```

After this, you can echo the contents you got inside the textarea or another element:

```
<textarea>
    <?php
        echo $csvData;
    ?>
</textarea>
```